# Convert multiple consequent invalid characters to one underline?

Tags: f#

The following string is not a valid file name.

```
"File   name\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t  (Revised 2018-05-31 15:35:41.16).txt"
```

The following code converts it to a valid file name.

```
let fn = """File   name

                  (Revised 2018-05-31 15:35:41.16).txt""";;
let invalid = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();;

String.Join("",
    fn |> Seq.filter(fun x -> 
        not (Array.exists (fun y -> y = x) invalid)
        ) 
)
// "File   name        (Revised 2018-05-31 153541.16).txt"
```

It just removes these invalid characters. How to convert these invalid to a `_`? For these multiple consequent invalid characters, I want them to be replaced to only one `_`. So the expected result should be

```
"File   name_  (Revised 2018-05-31 15_35_41.16).txt"
```

Comment: Replacing any combination of those characters with a regex is the simplest thing here; that works exactly the same as in C#. So you want something roughly like `Regex.Replace(fn, @"[\\n\\r\\t]+", "_")`.

Comment: Right, regular expression should be the simplest way. Just need to construct the pattern using System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let normalizeFileName name =
    let invalidPattern =
        System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
        |> Seq.map (string >> Regex.Escape)
        |> String.concat ""
        |> sprintf "[%s]+"

    Regex.Replace(name, invalidPattern, "_")
```